# How to identify which http request returned what result in mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, anypoint-studio, mule4

I am trying to migrate data from postgre to Hubspot. I am doing it with integration APIs provided by the Hubspot CRM. The number of API calls can reach up to 1000 at a time. I want to maintain logs showing which records were migrated successfully and which weren't. For this, I need to know which HTTP request returned the result. How can I implement this?

```
<flow name="migration-to-hubspootFlow" doc:id="0b2433b4-0de3-4f10-92e9-fc1014015043" >
        <scheduler doc:name="Scheduler" doc:id="63c6576a-1cca-4a17-b7d7-1f033ba88453" >
            <scheduling-strategy >
                <fixed-frequency frequency="60" timeUnit="MINUTES"/>
            </scheduling-strategy>
        </scheduler>
        <db:select doc:name="Select" doc:id="b258bb4c-6e34-4b66-a59f-8ae634975373" config-ref="Database_Config">
            <db:sql ><![CDATA[select distinct c.email, c.lastmodifieddate, c.id, c.sfid, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.title, c.phone,c.mailingstate, c.mailingstreet, c.mailingcity, c.mailingpostalcode, c.mailingcountry
from salesforceuat.contact c
where c.email is not null
limit 500]]></db:sql>
        </db:select>
        <batch:job jobName="migration-to-hubspootBatch_Job" doc:id="ba2f58cd-ddd2-4e28-911f-107d6e7333db" >
            <batch:process-records >
                <batch:step name="Batch_Step" doc:id="f4fa295c-bc1f-4c22-8fb3-6193f415cafb" >
                    <http:request method="POST" doc:name="Request" doc:id="c7eb69e0-0a43-4526-91e2-022469c203bc" config-ref="HTTP_Request_configuration" path="/contacts/v1/contact/createOrUpdate/email/{userEmail}/" sendBodyMode="ALWAYS" requestStreamingMode="AUTO">
                <http:body><![CDATA[#[%dw 2.0

output application/json

---

{
  "properties": [
    {
      "property": "JobTitle",
      "value": payload.title
    },
    {
      "property": "firstname",
      "value": payload.firstname
    },
    {
      "property": "lastname",
      "value": payload.lastname
    },
    {
      "property": "website",
      "value": ""
    },
    {
      "property": "company",
      "value": "HubSpot"
    },
    {
      "property": "phone",
      "value": payload.phone
    },
    {
      "property": "address",
      "value": payload.mailingstreet
    },
    {
      "property": "city",
      "value": payload.mailingcity
    },
    {
      "property": "state",
      "value": payload.mailingstate
    },
    {
      "property": "zip",
      "value": payload.mailingpostalcode
    }
  ]
}]]]></http:body>
                <http:headers><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "Host" : "api.hubapi.com",
    "Content-Type" : "application/json"
}]]]></http:headers>
                <http:uri-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "userEmail" : payload.email
}]]]></http:uri-params>
                <http:query-params><![CDATA[#[output application/java
---
{
    "hapikey" : "************"
}]]]></http:query-params>
            </http:request>
                    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="531d9bdf-3eca-4159-88b4-6ab86016927b" message="#[message.payload] #[message.attributes]" />
                </batch:step>
            </batch:process-records>
        </batch:job>
    </flow>
```

Comment: What do you mean by identifying the request? How do you know if a record migrated or not? Please provide examples of what would the expect output for each case.

Comment: @aled I made 1000 HTTP requests and got their responses. Most of the requests were successful and migrated the data but some were unsuccessful in migrating the data. I want to create the log that which HTTP requests successfully migrated the data and which couldn't.

Comment: How are you identifying if the request was unsuccessful? are you getting an error response? what is the HTTP Status of the response in that case? And what information do you want to log when the request fails?

Comment: @HarshankBansal Mostly I get 400 bad request errors in case of failure due to excess character count etc and 200 status codes in case of success. I'll update the record in the table as synced if I get a 200 status code and failed if I get 400 or any status code other than 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set maxFailedRecords to -1 ([docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-error-handling-faq)), then records that result in a mule error (like HTTP:BAD_REQUEST) can be handled in a subsequent batch step that uses acceptPolicy=ONLY_FAILURES ([docs](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.4/batch-filters-and-batch-aggregator)). There you can handle them one at a time or all together using a Batch Aggregator.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Ryan. I think I didn't explain well earlier.
Suppose I have records with IDs: 1 to 70. I made HTTPS requests (ID and other relevant data are in the HTTP request body) to post these records to Hubspot CRM and got 70 responses. Let's say 30 requests failed and 40 were successful. Now I want to make an update in my source database against ID records that were synced and which records failed. For this, I need to identify 'which HTTPS request body created a failure and which request was successful'. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi Faizan, The batch step will capture the failed records by design if you use the acceptPolicy.  The HTTP Request component will produce a HTTP:BAD_REQUEST for 400 responses and it will not produce an error for the 200 OK responses.

Comment: Hi @Ryan, The issue with acceptPolicy/Batch job is that it just returns the count. If I send 3 requests a,b and c and get responses d, e, and f. How can I identify that f belongs to which request? a or b or c? Batch job/acceptPolicy will just give me a num e.g. 2 failed and 1 successful.

Comment: Hello.  You are right, the BatchJobResult will have a count. However, you can add a subsequent batch step that uses ONLY_FAILURES policy, and that step will get the failed records.

Comment: thank you for the help. I have already implemented this and got the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Before an http call store the unique id in a variable and make a call to target and get the status and frame a message along with the status and unique Id.
store/process to MQ or in VM QM of success and failed records and process them back to DB to update the status.

Comment: Could you please share some examples or docs for that?

Comment: do you know how to attach a doc?

Comment: I think we can't attach a doc here. But you can share a drive link here.

Comment: https://github.com/sriram0891/circuite-breaker-http-conn-poc try this link

Comment: Hi @Ramachandra Setti, the client has asked me not to use Mule queue as it is a very costly solution for them. Can you please suggest some other solution?

Comment: You can use VM Q insted MQ